# Printing a DIV at specific dimensions

Tags: css, printing

I need to print some `<div>` tags at a specific dimension. In my print stylesheet I've specified with width and height as inches. However, the printed result is slightly larger (about 5-7mm larger on both dimensions).

Is there any way to get a very specific printed size?

Comment: Are you sure something else is going on, e.g. a printer "fitting to page"? If you really need something to print exactly, you'll have the least pain just making a PDF out of it.

Comment: How about your padding? Do you have padding on the `DIV`? If so, try removing the padding on the `DIV` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have a 2px margin, would that cause any problems, or only padding?

Comment: margin and padding are generally not affected by height and width css properties... so that could be your problem.

Comment: see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp for more info, it's not totally intuitive.

Comment: As I though, margin wouldn't effect the size from the border inwards. I have a border and from the border inwards needs to be the exact size. Since I have no padding, the width and height should still be correct, right? EDIT: The border is only 1px and prints very small, so that shouldn't be effecting the size by the magnitude I'm seeing.